# Prolog append to list

Tags: prolog

```
% Generator for natural numbers
isNatural(0).
isNatural(X) :-
  isNatural(Y),
  X is Y+1.

rangeToList(From, To, ResultList) :-
    isNatural(X),
    X > From, 
    X < To,
    % Add X to the ResultList
    appendTo(X, ResultList, ResultList),
    Tn is To - 1,
    % do the same with X to To-1
    rangeToList(From , Tn, ResultList).

% appendTo(+Number, +List, -NewList)
appendTo(Number, [], [Number]).
appendTo(Number, List, NewList) :-
    append(List, [Number], NewList).
```

How to append `X` to the `ResultList`? Whenever `appendTo` is reached `List = NewList` from the beginning which is not my intention, since I want to combine `List` and `[Number]` into `NewList`.

Comment: The symbols `+` and `-` in the signature of the predicate (third line from bottom) mean input/output. That seems mixed up in your code.

Comment: Fourth line from bottom.

Comment: You don't need `appendTo(Number, [], [Number]).` The clause `appendTo(Number, List, NewList) :- append(List, [Number], NewList).` would take care of that case. To your original problem, you cannot reassign Prolog variables. Once `ResultList` is instantiated, it cannot be re-instantiated except through backtracking. You're also missing a base case for `rangeToList/3`. It is either going to loop forever or fail. Overall, though, I think you've taken a cumbersome approach to your original problem. Perhaps you could explain what it is you want this thing to do.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to append to a list in a recursion because the variable is already bound. I just want to collect these numbers and return them in ResultList. How to append to a list and also return it at the same time?

Comment: You need two separate variables.

Comment: I already tried this:
`ResultListCpy = ResultList,
appendTo(X, ResultListCpy, ResultList),`
In appendTo it says List = NewList in trace and it doesn't work either. I get an out of stack error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has some problems: as said in the comments "you cannot reassign Prolog variables. Once `ResultList` is instantiated, it cannot be re-instantiated except through backtracking". Moreover you need a base case for `rangeToList` to stop it during recursion. Third problem: if you write `X > From, X < To` the program will loops forever because you decrement the value `To` each step so, at certain point, `From` will be equal to `To` and the program will loop (due to the way you wrote `isNatural/1`). Last but not the list, you need to call `appendTo/3` after the recursion call (i suggest you to turn this predicate into a tail recursive predicate, so the recursion call will be the last call). I've modified your program but i think this is not the result you want to obtain

```
isNatural(0).
isNatural(X) :-
  isNatural(Y),
  X is Y+1.

rangeToList(A,A,_).
rangeToList(From, To, ResultList) :-
    isNatural(X),
    X >= From, 
    X =< To,
    Tn is To - 1,
    rangeToList(From , Tn, ResultList1),
    appendTo(X, ResultList1, ResultList).

appendTo(Number, [], [Number]).
appendTo(Number, List, NewList) :-
    append(List, [Number], NewList).

?-rangeToList(1,3,L).
L = [2,2]
```

To obtain the actual list you need to change the way you generate numbers.
A solutions could be:

```
rangeToList(A,A,[A]).
rangeToList(From, To, ResultList) :-
    From =< To,
    From1 is From + 1,
    rangeToList(From1 , To, ResultList1),
    appendTo(From, ResultList1, ResultList).

appendTo(Number, [], [Number]).
appendTo(Number, List, NewList) :-
    append(List, [Number], NewList).

?-rangeToList(1,4).
L = [3,2,1]
```

Comment: The first example helped me a lot to understand the "you need two variables" and build the proper recursion. The second example gives me weird results `R = [3,2,1] ;
R = [3,2,1] ;
R = [_764,3,2,1] ;`

Comment: I've corrected the little problem: i've changed `rangeToList(A,A,_).` to `rangeToList(A,A,[A]).`